# Like button comments not placed correctly

Tags: facebook, wordpress, plugins

I am using the wordpress facebook plugin by facebook. When somebody clicks the like button, the  "add a comment" box pops up. Filling that one it is placed correctly in the news overview. In the timeline or profile page, the content is replaced by three or four lines with the letters "N/A". Checking this with other sites, the same thing happens. Is this a known bug? does anyone know a way to solve or work around it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a problem with you web browser.